# How to post value ckeditor - DecoupledEditor

Tags: ckeditor5

**I want to send the value with the version of Decoupled Editor in ckeditor but the value is null **

```
<div id="toolbar-container"></div>

<!-- This container will become the editable. -->
<div id="editor">
    <p>This is the initial editor content.</p>
</div>

<script>
    DecoupledEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector( '#toolbar-container' );

            toolbarContainer.appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

**But classic editor version worked**

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
```

ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );

Comment: if you want to use Ckeditor with a textArea in order to post the editor's content, you will have to use ClassicEditor, because the DecoupledEditor don't work with TextAreas , Tip :  you can normally use the DecoupledEditor with a <div> element , and store its content on a hidden textArea before posting the Form , I mean @ManiMuthuPandi has done a good implementation .

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue.

I have used a hidden textarea and filled the values for that textarea from the editor

```
<div id="toolbar-container"></div>
<div id="editor">
    <p>This is the initial editor content.</p>
</div>

<textarea style='display:none;' name='editor1' id='editor1'></textarea>

<script>
$(document).on('submit','.submit',function(){
    html = $("#editor").html()
    $("#editor1").val(html)
})
</script>
```

Now able to post the textarea values to next page

Answer (score 0):

i have find the soluiton and append the value in FormData

```
<div id="editor></div>

jQuery('#form').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      form = document.getElementById('form');
      formData = new FormData(form);
      formData.append('post', $('#editor').html());
});
```